# Firefox addon: sendMessage not working in tabs.onUpdated but does in browserAction.onClicked (background.js)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on migrating my Chrome extension into a Firefox addon. Honestly didn't think it would be that hard, but I've been trying to fix an issue of the background not wanting to send a message to the content script. (And yes, I've read everything online, but it just won't send the message inside an onUpdated listener)

**EDIT**

When I tried to put following line into the browserAction.onClicked listener it works, but it does not work in onUpdated?

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "isInstalled"});
});
```

**END EDIT**

And yes, the content script IS loaded, checked with an alert for the hostname.

Here's the code I used in the Chrome extension (background):

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                action: 'isInstalled'
            });
        });
```

Now here's what I have tried in Firefox addon (background):

```
var gettingActiveTab = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
        gettingActiveTab.then((tabs) => {
            browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
        });
```

Which is inside the browser.tabs.onUpdated listener as follows:

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo){

if(changeInfo.status === "complete"){

...

}
});
```

I also tried this, as I thought it would work: (yes tabId is correct).

```
browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {action: "isInstalled"});
```

Now here's the onMessage listener on content script

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
if(request.action == "isInstalled"){
    alert("received");
    var isInstalledNode = document.createElement('div');
    isInstalledNode.id = 'extension-is-installed';
    document.body.appendChild(isInstalledNode);
}
});
```

I keep getting the following error: "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." which makes absolutely no sense for me.. Can anyone see the problem?

By the way, here's the manifest file:

```
{
"name": "Addon name",
"version": "1.3.0",
"manifest_version": 2,

"description": "...",
"icons": {
    "48": "assets/images/icon_48_active.png",
    "96": "assets/images/icon_96_active.png"
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Name"
},

"background": {
"scripts":["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "js": ["contentscript.js"]
}
],
"permissions": [
"cookies", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "modal.html", "assets/images/*"
]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other error messages? I just tried your code and it works.

Comment: Did you try it in the browserAction or on tabs.onUpdated?

Comment: ```browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo){
    
    if(changeInfo.status === "complete"){
    
        var gettingActiveTab = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
        gettingActiveTab.then((tabs) => {
            console.log('sending');
            console.log(tabs[0].id);
            browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
        });
    
    }
});```

Comment: Weird, for some reason it will not work for me when I put it in onUpdated, but works when I put it in a listener for the browseraction clicked.

Comment: And to answer your question, no, I'm not getting any other errors.

Comment: Guess I'm gonna try to do some more troubleshooting, because this makes absolutely no sense to me

Comment: Does it work if you add "run_at": "document_start" in the "content_scripts" section of the manifest?